# How do I stay on the same page after submitting a post request and hit another post request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I'm doing a one page website where I'm wanting to input some text and upload files. Basically, how I want my form to look like at the front end is, first I can type some text in the textarea given, below that I should be able to select multiple files, once the files are selected I'll click on the upload button, the files should be uploaded, and then I'll hit submit and that's how I create a post.

I'm attaching my code below. I do have written my broken `views.py` file but I'm not attaching it for now.

```
models.py :
class Post(models.Model): 
    post_body = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=500)   

class PostMedia(models.Model): 
    file = models.FileField()
    body = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
forms.py :

from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post, PostMedia


class PostModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_body']


class PostMediaModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostMedia
        fields = ['file']
        widgets = {
            'file': ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
```

```
form.html (I was trying to write the jquery function):

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $('text-form').on('submit',upload(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.post( '../create-post', $('form').serialize(), function( data ) {
               alert( data );
          } );
    });
</script>
    <div class="site-form">
        <h2>Create a New Post here! </h2>
        <form action="." method="post" name="text-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <br><br>

            <form action="." method="post" name="file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ file_form }}
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload files" onclick="upload(); return false;"/>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Create post"/>
            </form>

        </form>
    </div>
```

```
urls.py

 url(r'^/create-post', upload_files, name='create-post'),
 url(r'^/submit-post', submit_post, name='submit-post'),
```

Now, I want that when I click the upload button I should stay on the very same page but in the background, in the `views.py` it should actually save the selected files(taking into consideration that I can not save the files unless and untill I'm saving the text bcz of the foreignkey), and then I can click the submit button to save the post.

How do I achieve this? Just giving the workflow will also be appreciated. I've no knowledge of jquery or ajax, I'm guessing they do the trick here..

Comment: You can use as much ajax request you want and stay on same page

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari Can you please answer the question?

Comment: @Ken4scholars need your guidance..

Answer (score 0):

Well i think i can help you with the javascript

```
<button onclick="upload(); return false;">Upload files<button/>

<input type="submit" id="create_post_button" value="Create post"/>
```

Inside the first script tag add

```
$(function() {
     $("#create_post_button").hide();
 });
```

If you dont want that the create post button be shown until you upload a file.

then in the upload function

```
function upload(){ event.preventDefault(); 
data = new FormData();
data.append( 'file', $( '#file' )[0].files[0] );
//files if is multiple
//is necessaty add an id to make it easier but you can access to the html element with $(input[name='inputname']) if you want to keep wht input type button

$.ajax({
    url: 'url to post',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
       $("#create_post_button").show();   

   }
});}
```

i suggest you if the input file should not be inside the form you move it away from it for example below the  tag that close form because if not you will send the file two times and is not necessary. if you just want that when there is a file  then you can upload all the form i suggest you to do this

add an id to the form and then

```
$("#formreference").submit(function(){
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); //with this form data send to server with a post request similar that the shown before });
```

i think is better idea read the dom event of submit, in that case on the upload function only need

```
function upload(){ event.preventDefault(); $("#create_post_button").show();}
```